# Nesting Div's to build footer (have tried clear:both)

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to get the below "container" to be recognized as the wrapper div and take on the height of the other elements.  This is so I can dynamically size the other elements and the container resizes placing the footer at the bottom.

I've looked all over (for a couple of hours now!) at the solution and everywhere mentions clear:both or overflow:auto, neither of which seem to be working

Would really love it if some one can point out where I'm going wrong!

```
<HTML>
<head>

    <style type="text/css"> 
    body {
                text-align: left;
                font-size: small;
        }
    #Layer-2 {
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: -640px;
                left: 50%;
                top: +0px;
                width: 1280px;
                z-index: 2;
            }


    #Layer-3 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 146px;
                top: 33px;
                width: 687px;
                height: 59px;
                z-index: 3;
            }


    #Layer-4 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 157px;
                top: 125px;
                width: 174px;
                height: 843px;
                z-index: 4;
            }


    #Layer-5 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 361px;
                top: 286px;
                width: 776px;
                height: 682px;
                z-index: 5;
                overflow: auto;
            }
    hr {
            display: block; 
            clear: left; 
            margin: -0.66em 0;
            visibility: hidden;
    }

#container {overflow:hidden;}


    </Style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="Layer-2">

            <div id="Layer-5"  >
            Hello World
            </div>

            <div id="Layer-4" >
            Hello World 2
            </div>

            <div id="Layer-3" >
            Hows Things today?
            </div>
        <hr>
         <br style="clear: both; height: 0; visibility: hidden;">
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both; height: 0; visibility: hidden;">
</div>  
    <div WIDTH="100%"> Footer </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLuw/1/) of your code after some corrections. Notice that I have added borders to all the `div` elements in order to see how everithing is nested. Your "issue" is the `position:absolute` in all of the `div`s CSS rule. I have also removed all the `z-index` rules, because they are no longer neccsary.

Looking at your code, you have some issues that need to be fixed:

- when you apply `position:absolute` to an element, it takes the element out of the natural flow, meaning that it will not affect the rest of the elemnts. This is why your footer was at the top of the document.
- `br` and `hr` are empty elements, and should be written like this: `<br />` and `<hr />` etc.
- I would reccomend keeping all the css styling in the `<style>` area instead of having it all over the place with inline style. Eg: instead of `<div WIDTH="100%">` use css like `#footer {width:100%}` and place it in the head of the document or in an external file.
- `overflow:hidden` and `clear:both` should always work. If they dont, check your code for errors.

Comment: Hi,

Cheers for the reply! 

I'm using the absolute positioning to position a menu, title and content and so need the Divs to be absolutely positioned.  Looking around the forums I found that most people recommend using the clear:both function or some variant to solve the positioning issue.

However, this doesn't seem to be working above, any ideas?

Also completely agree with the tidying up into the style sheet but was in a rush, apologies

Comment: Using `position:absolute` takes the element out of the flow, and therefor `clear:both` or equivilant simply would'nt work. If you must absolute position your elements, the only way you could achieve what your trying to do is by placing the footer inside the bottom element. here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLuw/2/ . Keep in mind that the right way to do this is by `position:static` and floating.

Comment: Ahhh, i have seen the error of my ways (teach me for hashing code!) THANKS!